# How to find representation for $b_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was asked to find $b_n$ where $a_n= \{x \in R \mid 4 \leq x \leq 2n+2\}$.

How can I find $b_n$?

I've already tried to do $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$, but I got $0 \leq 0 \leq 2$ which might be correct, but obviously wrong.

How can I represent $b_n$?

Comment: I can't understand your question. What are the $b_n$'s? Also, it looks like $a_n$'s are sets, e.g $a_2 = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 4 \leq x \leq 6 \}$, which is probably not what you mean.

Comment: is $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$?

Comment: tried to write it as a set, i.e {} but for some reason when i posted it, it erased it. the definition of $a_n$ should be in {}.

Comment: @BeginningMath, to make the curly brackets appear inside dollar signs, preface them with backslashes:  "\{" and "\}."

Comment: I edited your question to make the curly braces visible as you seemed to intend them to be; does it correctly represent the the question you meant to ask? (You had doubled the curly brackets; I wasn't sure if you really meant that or if it was just an attempt to get at least _one_ bracket to show up.)

Comment: How do you define $a_{n+1} - a_n$ if $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ are sets (as the apparently were meant to be)? Is this meant to be the difference between the sets?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$4\le a_n\le 2n+2$$

$$\implies -2n-2\le -a_n\le -4$$
$$4\le a_{n+1}\le 2(n+1)+2$$

thus by sum

$$-2n+2\le a_{n+1}-a_n\le 2n $$

Comment: how could you understand this question???

Comment: ha ha ... that can be understandable by your last comment before it was edited!

Comment: may i please ask how would you compute $\bigcap_{2\leq n \in N} B_n$? i am learning a lot from your input and learning what i do wrong